# Cant upload an app- stack on uploading

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I guess that question have been asked yet , but i wonder if there is something else .
I have `archived` my app , check `validate` , than hit `distribute` .
It usually takes time, but today, i am trying of 8 (!!) hours to upload an update to an app.
iTunes connect is `ready for upload binary` .

I have tried to start again many times (after 1-2 hour stack in the window :

```
Your application is being uploaded //status bar have not even started
```

I just cant figure out why every time you are trying to upload an app,it takes so much time,
and **today** , its just not working .

Could be a problem with my app that the validation have not seen ?
The app is just 12M size.

What else can you do ?

Comment: Probably better off asked in the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: no help there. i am just lost. no error nothing. just on hold.